# Using $ to find a column in loops in r not working

Tags: r, loops

I have been trying to find an answer to this on stack but I can not.

It is a pretty simple question, I am basically trying to understand why in some cases the item in my loop will take on values but in other times it will not.

For example:

```
for (i in colnames(df)) {
    print(unique(df$i)
}
```

Nothing appears, shouldn't it work? Should for the first iteration `df$i` take on `df$names` of column 1. However when I instead type `df[i]`, it does. I am trying to understand how exactly `i` is taking on different names in the loop when it will work and when it will not.

Here is another example I am trying to understand

```
for (var in var_names) {
    print(var)
    var_vector <-sum(case_when(df$x == var ~ df$y)
    table<- cbind(table,var_vector)
}
```

For this I thought that var_vector would be called something different each time like x_vector, y_vector, etc. However, instead it is just called var_vector for each iteration of the loop. Is there a way to specify in the loop make all the "var"'s in a loop take on that value. For example if you are familiar with stata `var'_vector would rename the vector different with each iteration.

Comment: For the first question, use brackets instead of $, `print(unique(df[i]))` will return a data.frame with only named column i, `print(unique(df[[i]]))` will return a vector with the values of column i. test with mtcars to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure that this is the best practice, but you could use `assign`. It really depends more on the context I think.

```r
x <- LETTERS[1:3]

for(i in seq_along(x)){
  
  assign(paste0(x[i], "_vector"), runif(10))
  
}

A_vector
#>  [1] 0.4221484184 0.6695296315 0.3161487477 0.4168466690 0.1906193914
#>  [6] 0.2252857985 0.0005740104 0.6336193492 0.7917131276 0.2764370542
B_vector
#>  [1] 0.3575036 0.3554171 0.6053375 0.9268683 0.2017908 0.4303173 0.6608523
#>  [8] 0.2539930 0.8057227 0.0895042
C_vector
#>  [1] 0.1287253 0.4172858 0.2453591 0.2957820 0.2213195 0.2940916 0.6900414
#>  [8] 0.5104015 0.8996254 0.7504864
```